# How does one add extremely large values in Java?

Tags: java

I've tried the code below, but I'm getting an error.  How would I go about adding two large values represented as strings together?

```
public class LargeAddition {

    static String testcase1 = "987659876598765";
    static String testcase2 = "9999999999999999999999999988888888888";//can we add this kind of large num

    public static void main(String args[]){
        LargeAddition testInstance = new LargeAddition();
        String result = testInstance.add(testcase1,testcase2);
        System.out.println("Result : "+result);

    }

    //write your code here
    public String add(String str1, String str2){
        Long num=000000000000000L;
        //String str="";
        num=Long.parseLong(str1)+Long.parseLong(str2);
        //String str=num.toString();

        return num.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out `BigInteger`.

Comment: any thing without Big integer..............

Comment: Yup.  Lots of Java code.  Start writing :-)

Comment: :( i had an assignment to complete...........

Comment: Check how `BigInteger` does it.

Comment: What's wrong with BigInteger?  You could always use a DoublyLinkedList containing Integer values.  Then create a calculation system.  It's a lot of code....but it's good practice!

Comment: Looks like your teacher is trying to nudge you towards a string-based solution (which is very inefficient but I guess it's to get you thinking the right way)

Comment: take each string in reverse, parse the character to a single digit and add it to the corresponding digit in the other string.  Calculate the carry, and proceed to the next characters.  Rinse/repeat until you've exhausted one string and your carry.  that should work for any arbitrarily large number

Comment: @user3229433 do it as you'd do math calculation by hand. I hope you can do addition on large numbers without calculator? You can do the same thing. It's not hard to do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's an assigment and there is no real work done yet.

Comment: And you need to have arrays of `longs`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BigInteger`, `Long` is short for these values.

```
public static String add(String str1, String str2) {
    BigInteger big1 = new BigInteger(str1);
    BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger(str2);

    final BigInteger num = big1.add(big2);
    return num.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an a homework assignment and you don't/can't use classes such as `BigInteger`, I'll go through a more tedious and manual way to do it (although a good introduction assignment).

You can loop through the two String-integers from size-1 to 0.

```
String integer1 = "1230"
String integer2 = "9999999"

for(int i = integer1.size; i >= 0; i--){
    //addition
}
```

However, this is may be an issue since the two String-integers have different sizes.  I would create a method that will add additional zeroes to the front of the smaller String-integer so both String-integers match in size.  Ex. `"1230"  -> "0001230"`

Before looping, create an output String-inter which equals to an empty-String.

```
String outputInt = "";
```

Convert each char to an int, then do the addition.

```
int tempResult = Integer.parseInteger(integer1.indexOf(i)) + Integer.parseInteger(integer2.indexOf(i))
```

If you get a single digit, convert it to a String and append to output String-integer.  If you get a double digit, then only put append the second digit and carry over the first digit to the next calculation.

```
String tempResultStr = //convert tempResult into a String
if(tempResultStr .size == 1){
    //handle single digit case
}else{
    //handle double digit case
    //use a variable to declare carry over
}
```

Remember to handle the case if you have to carry over and there is nothing to carry over to.

**NOTE**:  This is pseudo code for most part

Comment: You seem to be just thinking out loud. Have you ever done this? The JRE already contains not one but two classes that already do it correctly.

Comment: @EJP  So you're telling me you don't think this is a homework assignment given to understand how computers add?  It's not thinking out loud.  I'm giving him a simple direction to go without using BigInteger or other classes like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

you'll get

```
9223372036854775807
```

your values are far greater

```
9999999999999999999999999988888888888
```

so the way is to use BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("9999999999999999999999999988888888888");        
System.out.println(bd.multiply(bd));
```

gives you

```
99999999999999999999999999777777777760000000000000000123456790143209876544
```